# custom control binding with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net

I have custom control MyGrid

```
public class MyGrid : Canvas
{
//...
    ObservableCollection<object> items = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set { 
            items = value;
            UpdateValues();
            UpdateGrid();
        }
    }
    //..
}
```

And I want Items to be bindable from XAML code:

```
<local:MyGrid Items="{Binding Numbers}" />
```

Where Numbers is ObservableCollection (which works fine, I can use it to bind to default controls).
I've tried to define Items as DependencyProperty, but it is static and I need to use more than one control on page with different sources of data, so using static items won't work. The code above doesn't work as well. InitializeComponent() throws an exception: Failed to assign to property 'App.MyGrid.Items'. [Line: 27 Position: 114]. How can I make it work?

Comment: The Items collection is declared as an attribute but for binding you need to declare it as an public property. Hope this helps you out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188782/adding-properties-to-custom-wpf-control

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I posted wrong code, I'm using public property. Code in post updated

Comment: @Icepickle : Did I get your idea right? Edited code like that:
     public readonly ObservableCollection<object> items = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items
        {
            get { return items; }
            set { }
        }

And it still doesn't work.

Comment: @EricTroy, never mind, i was mistaken :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your MyGrid extends from Canvas (Which is long last also a DependecyObject) you could implement the Dependency property inside the MyGrid.

You could then also implement it with a `PropertyChangedCallback` which would allow you to register/unregister to the event itself, where you could then update your grid / values

So you could change the MyGrid like this:

```
public class MyGrid : Canvas
{
    protected static PropertyChangedCallback ItemsPropertyChangedCallback = new PropertyChangedCallback(ItemsPropertyChanged);

    public static DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Items", typeof(INotifyCollectionChanged), typeof(MyGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null, ItemsPropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void ItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyGrid thisGrid = (MyGrid)sender;
        if (thisGrid == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        thisGrid.UnregisterItems(e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged);
        thisGrid.RegisterItems(e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged);
        thisGrid.Refresh();
    }

    public INotifyCollectionChanged Items 
    { 
        get
        {
            return (INotifyCollectionChanged)GetValue(ItemsProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected void UnregisterItems(INotifyCollectionChanged items)
    {
        if (items == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        items.CollectionChanged -= ItemsChanged;
    }

    protected void RegisterItems(INotifyCollectionChanged items)
    {
        if (items == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        items.CollectionChanged += ItemsChanged;
    }

    protected virtual void UpdateValues()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Updating values");
    }

    protected virtual void UpdateGrid()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Updating grid");
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        UpdateValues();
        UpdateGrid();
    }

    protected virtual void ItemsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }

    public MyGrid()
    {
    }
}
```

and in Xaml you could then later on Bind to the Items property. When the Items property is changed with another collection, it will unregister from the changed event of the last object (if there was one), and then register to the new object (if there is one). Afterwards, it will call the Refresh method of your class (that then calls the UpdateValues / UpdateGrid methods)

I also partly agree with @user3248647 that you should take advantage of Binding and ContentTemplates when you can, but if you cannot use that, you could get your DependencyProperty reacting at least like this.

And yes, the DependencyProperty is static on the class, but the property itself is always implemented inside the class. When using the PropertyChangedCallback, just cast the sender back to "MyGrid" and then you can change the instance members :)

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,5,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding yourVariable}" Height="16"/>
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding yourVariable1}" FontSize="26"/>
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding yourVariable2}" FontSize="10" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                    </StackPanel>                        
                </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                </WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

This may be not actually what you looking for. But I think this can help you.