# WPF How to get multiple values to template?

Tags: wpf, styles

[want to code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxNoy.png)

```
<Style x:Key="TestButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>

                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50">line01</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="80">line02</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I want to reuse this template.
The template need two changeable values.
I only learned that {TemplateBinding something}
How to expand values?

Comment: can you explain in details with the required result, which changeable values etc.

Comment: You can bind `Text ="{TemplatedBinding Name}"` as first textBlock and `Text={TemplatedBinding Uid}` as second textBlock, but more universal way would be to create custom control with 2 content properties and deriving from button instead of using button

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your custom control with Dependency Property from C#.

```
DependencyProperty.Register("My_Property_Name_1", typeof(String), typeof(Custom_Control));
DependencyProperty.Register("My_Property_Name_2", typeof(String), typeof(Custom_Control));
```

Already a similar question has answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188782/adding-properties-to-custom-wpf-control).